# Select values from elements with the particular class name

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I am getting an object reference error when parsing an external html file, I think this is because not all the elements selected have the class name. Here is my code:

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Where(i => i.Attributes["class"].Value == "name"))
{
    string result = link.InnerText.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

How do select only the values where I have the class name of "name"?

Here is my html code I'm trying to parse:

```html
<li>
    <span class="name">
        <a href="/players/joe-bloggs.html">Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs</a>
    </span>

    <span class="country">
        <img src="/img/flags/15x15/USA.gif" alt="USA"/>
        United States
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">
        <a href="/players/joe-bloggs.html">Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs</a>
    </span>

    <span class="country">
        <img src="/img/flags/15x15/USA.gif" alt="USA"/>
        United States
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">
        <a href="/players/joe-bloggs.html">Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs</a>
    </span>

    <span class="country">
        <img src="/img/flags/15x15/RSA.gif" alt="RSA"/>
        South Africa
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you show the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select `a` elements instead of `li` elements. And its `span` element which have `class` attribute. I suggest you to use predicates:

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li/span[@class='name']/a");
```

This xpath selects all `span` elements which have `class` attribute equal to `name`, and then selects `a` element.

```
foreach (var a in links)
    Console.WriteLine(a.InnerText);
```

For your sample HTML output is:

```
Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs
Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs
Joe,&nbsp;Bloggs
```

Side note - you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(a.InnerText)` to get decoded text (not only `&nbsp;` will be replaced).

---

UPDATE: Parsing players

```
var players = from p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")
              let name = p.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='name']/a")
              let country = p.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='country']")
              select new
              {
                  Name = (name == null) ? null : 
                         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(name.InnerText.Trim()),
                  Country = (country == null) ? null :
                         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(country.InnerText.Trim())
              };
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    Name: "Joe, Bloggs",
    Country: "United States"
  },
  {
    Name: "Joe, Bloggs",
    Country: "United States"
  },
  {
    Name: "Joe, Bloggs",
    Country: "South Africa"
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice answer. Can you explain why the OP's original method doesn't work? I have re-read it a few times and can't see why.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the name & the country from the html given above? They are both in the same li, I only need the text values.

Comment: @Rondles he was checking `class` attribute on `li` elements. But this attrubute acutally sits on `span` elements

Comment: That's what I thought too initially, but then I noticed his use of Descendants. Shouldn't this select everything within each `li` element?

Comment: @Rondles nope, that selects all `li` elements from any locations of document

Comment: Right, so it selects all descendants from the document which are `li` and not all descendants within an `li`? So could he have instead done: `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Descendants("span").Where(i => i.Attributes["class"].Value == "name")`

Comment: @Rondles yes, that is alternative solution

Comment: @Sergey thank you for clarifying. I was totally unaware of the technique you've used and will be using it for sure.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I just wanted to say thank you for the solution provided above! I was exactly what I was after.